# Has a Cloth Simulation ever been done in WPF or Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, graphics, 3d, simulation

I'm trying to find out **if any sample Cloth simulation exists with code in WPF or Silverlight**.

So far this is what I've found:

- It's been done in DirectX and then used as an ImageBrush in WPF, but I mean without a DirectX and without a C++ dependency.
- It's been done in Flash and even Javascript so it's definitely possible performance wise:
  http://www.andrew-hoyer.com/experiments/cloth
- There are a few .NET physics libraries but are mostly 2d only (or don't support soft body systems)

So would I really be the first one on the planet to do this in Silverlight?  That's hard to believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but you are not the first ;).

Check this demo from Oscar Oto: http://www.raonalab.com/silverlightme (under the Real3D Tab). Behind the scene it uses [Kit3D](http://kit3d.codeplex.com/) - a 3D C# graphics engine for Microsoft Silverlight.

Comment: I'm impressed - you've answer my question.

Comment: Btw, two aspects that would be very nice to have:

Comment: 1)  Free source code  2)  Interactivity.  I think for the sake of these points I'll still be writing my own version.

Comment: Good luck, Faraday. I'd love to see your solution! Please share when you implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my site http://rene-schulte.info
I implemented a soft body system for it. Also see my older projects. And my blog for the details about my site.